# AWS S3 Angular Access Denied

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get the files in my S3 bucket and trying to download them but when I click on them it opens up a page with this error

```
<Error>
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
 <Message>Access Denied</Message>
 <RequestId>FE17C7B6E365BAD4</RequestId>
 <HostId>ujchseKLaqfZmxSim8WnC8oNLH/59KyE6JJUKZ1UFp7daOq/OnlAAjY1nkw2ZYDWlokZN4R17g0=</HostId>
</Error>
```

An the console says
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

This is the piece of code I'm using to get the documents

```
getFiles(): Observable<Array<FileUpload>> {
 const fileUploads = new Array<FileUpload>();

 const params = {
  Bucket: this.BUCKET,
 };

this.getS3Bucket().listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There was an error getting your files: ' + err);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Successfully get files.', data);

  const fileDatas = data.Contents;

  fileDatas.forEach(function (file) {
    fileUploads.push(new FileUpload(file.Key, 'https://xtec123.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' + '/' + file.Key));
  });
});
return of(fileUploads);
}
```

The access is totally set up to public no restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alow public access permissions from s3 bucket

[image]

Comment: All my access is set up in that way. All is in off. I don't have any bucket policy also all the ACL have all the permissions. But still have the same error

Comment: did you set your accessKeyId, secretAccessKey and region properly?